Can every color between red and green be made using monochromatic light?
Is it true that every color between red and green, can be made using monochromatic light. I think is should be true according to the visible spectrum. I may only need to increase or decrease the intensity of the color.


Perceived color is a 2-d space (with brightness being a 3rd dimension of our visual perception). There is only one line through this space between red and green that can be produced by monochromatic sources. There are an infinitude of other paths between red and green that include colors that can't be produced by monochromatic sources.

This is a close to being a repost of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/830709/174766.

This question is similar to: Why can colours like RGB $(168, 151, 80)$ be seen by humans?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Color is simply not a concept in physics. Physics deals with frequency and wavelength, not redness and greenness. How light is perceived by the human visual system as having color is biology and psychology, not physics.

"Every color between red and green" in what space? The picture in your question represents the one-dimensional space of monochromatic colors. It has a red and it has a green, and every color between them (as well as every other color in that particular space) can be  produced with a single frequency of light.

You may benefit from reading Poynton's Color FAQ. It's a bit dated, but most of the info is still relevant because modern display technology was designed to replace CRT technology without major color distortions.

This is a close to being a repost On a new account with the same username.

In industrial application, we assume three color-detecting cell model that approximate human response. Then approximate the observed colors of the single frequency by linear combination of the three. This is called
CIE 1931 color space. In here, if you pick just two monochromatic color as basis, by linear combination, you can just express a line in the color space. By combination of three, we can approximate the color space, but not fully. Many displaying industries wants to express as much color space their combination cover, so, there are many standards out there.


By the way, I noticed https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/830709/why-can-colours-like-rgb-168-151-80-be-seen-by-humans had more detailed answer there. If you are interested, I recommend to read the answer of it.
